# SQL Server not returning any rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the below query and it is returning with no data. However, if I run it without using the where clause, it's giving me the data. But I need to include the where conditions. Some variables have multiple values, so have used them using 'In'

```
DECLARE @start as DATETIME, @end as DATETIME, 
        @Effective_dt as datetime, @Expiry_dt as datetime, 
        @Strategic_Account as varchar (Max),
        @BIC_PILOT as varchar(max),
        @BIC as varchar(max), 
        @Active as varchar (max)

SET @start = '8/1/2016'
SET @end = '8/31/2016'

select * 
from 
     (
    Select 
        B.Strategic_Account, b.expiry_dt,
        isnull(b.bic_pilot,'No') as BIC_PILOT,
        A.*, B.TIN, B.BIC,
        Case 
           when B.Phase = 'Beta' 
              then 'Phase 1' 
           else B.Phase 
        end as Phase, 
        b.region
    from 
        (SELECT 
             CASE 
                WHEN Site IN ('Albuquerque', 'CSMiami', 'Detroit', 'Houston', 'Kingsport', 'Phoenix', 'Pittsburgh', 'Ridgeland', 'CSHonolulu')  
                   THEN 'C&S' 
                ELSE Site 
             END AS 'Line of Business',
             CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month,
             Site,
             skillnumber, VCCNode, calldate, 
             IVRCallerType,
             SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys,
             Question,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No,
             ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID, SurveyID
         FROM            
             (/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
              SELECT 
                  Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, 
                  calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType, 
                  ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
              FROM            
                  (SELECT        
                       Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, 
                       SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType, 
                       ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID, SurveyID
                   FROM            
                       SRVY_InsightData
                   WHERE        
                       --IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
                       IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake')
                       AND (VCCNODE IN ('Chaska Node 2', 'Plymouth Node 1', 'Chaska Node 14', 'Chaska 14') OR VCCNode IS NULL)
                       AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
                       AND Q7 <> '0' 
                       AND (Site IN('Albuquerque', 'CSMiami', 'Detroit', 'Houston', 'Kingsport', 'Phoenix', 'Pitts5urgh', 'Ridgeland', 'CSHonolulu')
                       AND skillnumber IN ('728','729','730','731','732','1369','1371','1376','1380','1396','309', '311','321', '323', '326', '765', '766', '767', '768', '769','169','204','480','481','483','484','486','487','488','489','490','491','719','364', '1694','1695','1696','1697','1698','1699','1700','1701','1702','1703','1704','1705','1706','1707','1708','1709','1710','1711','1712','1713','1714','1715','1716','1717','1718','1719','1720','1721','1722','1723','1724','1725','1726','1727'))
                       AND SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID 
                                             FROM SRVY_InsightData_Excpt)  
                       --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  
                       AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end) pvt 
               UNPIVOT 
                    (Response FOR Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
            GROUP BY 
                Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, 
                skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType, ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID, 
                SurveyID

UNION ALL

/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/* 4/12/2016 removed skills '220','222', '523', '524', '525','526', '538', '539', '540', '548',
add in skills '439','440' eff 4/1/2016   */

--DECLARE @start as DATETIME, @end as DATETIME
--SET @start = '5/1/2015'
--SET @end = '5/31/2015'

SELECT CASE WHEN site IN ('Oldsmar', 'Huntsville', 'Moline PHS', 'Manila', 'MnR_Manila') THEN 'M&R' 
ELSE Site END AS 'Line of Business'
, CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month
, Site
, skillnumber
, VCCNode
, calldate
, IVRCallerType
, SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys
, Question
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes 
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
SELECT Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(SELECT        Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            SRVY_InsightData
WHERE        
--IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake') 

AND (VCCNODE IN ('Plymouth Node 3','Chaska Node 14', 'Chaska 14')or VCCNode IS NULL)
AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
AND Q7 <> '0' 
and (Site in ('Oldsmar', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Huntsville') and SkillNumber in ('407','408','409','410','411','412','413','414', '439','440'))

and SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID from SRVY_InsightData_Excpt) --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  

AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pvt UNPIVOT 
(Response FOR 
Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
GROUP BY Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID


UNION ALL

/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/

/* removed  '1180', '1209', '834', '809','718', ,'1074' '1392','1393',
added in  '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519'
*/

SELECT CASE
WHEN Site In ('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila', 'Int_Frederick', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu') THEN 'E&I'
ELSE Site END AS 'Line of Business'
, CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month
, Site
, skillnumber
, VCCNode
, calldate
, IVRCallerType
, SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys
, Question
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes 
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
SELECT Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(SELECT        Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            SRVY_InsightData
WHERE        
--IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake')
AND (VCCNODE IN ('Eagan Node 7','Plymouth Node 1', 'Eagan Node 5') or VCCNode IS NULL)
AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
AND Q7 <> '0' 
AND (((Site IN('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila',  'Int_Frederick', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu', 'PHS_Manila')
AND skillnumber IN ('718','735','736','1689','1690', '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519'))
 and CallDate < '2/1/2015') 

or ((Site IN('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu', 'PHS_Manila')
AND skillnumber IN ('718','735','736','1689','1690', '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519')) 
and CallDate >= '2/1/2015'))-- adding code to remove INT_Frederick after 2/1/2015 - FLH
AND SkillNumber not IN ('777', '215', '217','235','249') 
and SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID from SRVY_InsightData_Excpt) --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  


AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pvt UNPIVOT 
(Response FOR 
Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
GROUP BY Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID, SurveyID

) A left join D_PPSM_TINs B on A.ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID=B.TIN 
) final 
where
[BIC_PILOT] in (@BIC_PILOT)
and
Case when [Strategic_Account] is Null then 'Null' else [Strategic_Account]  end  in (@Strategic_Account)
and
Case  when BIC is Null then 'No' else 'Yes' end in (@BIC)
and
case when Expiry_dt = convert(varchar(10),'12/31/9999',121) then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end in (@Active)
```

This is what I get without Where clause :-

[image]

Comment: What's the data type of `BIC_PILOT`,`BIC` and What you pass in `@BIC_PILOT` and `@BIC`??

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Both have varchar as their data types and @BIC_PILOT includes 'Yes','No' and 'Null' and '@BIC' includes 'Yes','No'

Comment: @JibinBalachandran .. Both have varchar as their data types and '@BIC_PILOT' includes 'Yes','No' and 'Null' and '@BIC' includes 'Yes','No'

Comment: As you probably already know, you can't use any kind of string variables in `in` clause and expect it to match to several values. It will only match that exact string. You need to do some kind of kludge or use table valued parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `IN` with `CHARINDEX`, it will check if the text exists in the comma separated string or not.

```
Select B.Strategic_Account,b.expiry_dt,
isnull(b.bic_pilot,'No') as BIC_PILOT,
A.*, B.TIN,B.BIC,Case when B.Phase ='Beta' then 'Phase 1' else B.Phase end as Phase, 
b.region
from (
SELECT CASE 
WHEN Site IN ('Albuquerque', 'CSMiami', 'Detroit', 'Houston', 'Kingsport', 'Phoenix', 'Pittsburgh', 'Ridgeland', 'CSHonolulu') THEN 'C&S' 
ELSE Site END AS 'Line of Business'
, CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month
, Site
, skillnumber
, VCCNode
, calldate
, IVRCallerType
, SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys
, Question
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes 
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
SELECT Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(SELECT        Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            SRVY_InsightData
WHERE        
--IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake')
AND (VCCNODE IN ('Chaska Node 2', 'Plymouth Node 1','Chaska Node 14','Chaska 14')or VCCNode IS NULL)
AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
AND Q7 <> '0' 
AND (Site IN('Albuquerque', 'CSMiami', 'Detroit', 'Houston', 'Kingsport', 'Phoenix', 'Pitts5urgh', 'Ridgeland', 'CSHonolulu')
AND skillnumber IN ('728','729','730','731','732','1369','1371','1376','1380','1396','309', '311','321', '323', '326', '765', '766', '767', '768', '769','169','204','480','481','483','484','486','487','488','489','490','491','719','364',
'1694','1695','1696','1697','1698','1699','1700','1701','1702','1703','1704','1705','1706','1707','1708','1709','1710','1711','1712','1713','1714','1715','1716','1717','1718','1719','1720','1721','1722','1723','1724','1725','1726','1727'))

and SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID from SRVY_InsightData_Excpt) --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  

AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pvt UNPIVOT 
(Response FOR 
Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
GROUP BY Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID


UNION ALL

/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  MEDICARE AND RETIREMENT ******************************************************************/
/* 4/12/2016 removed skills '220','222', '523', '524', '525','526', '538', '539', '540', '548',
add in skills '439','440' eff 4/1/2016   */

--DECLARE @start as DATETIME, @end as DATETIME
--SET @start = '5/1/2015'
--SET @end = '5/31/2015'

SELECT CASE WHEN site IN ('Oldsmar', 'Huntsville', 'Moline PHS', 'Manila', 'MnR_Manila') THEN 'M&R' 
ELSE Site END AS 'Line of Business'
, CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month
, Site
, skillnumber
, VCCNode
, calldate
, IVRCallerType
, SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys
, Question
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes 
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
SELECT Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(SELECT        Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            SRVY_InsightData
WHERE        
--IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake') 

AND (VCCNODE IN ('Plymouth Node 3','Chaska Node 14', 'Chaska 14')or VCCNode IS NULL)
AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
AND Q7 <> '0' 
and (Site in ('Oldsmar', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Huntsville') and SkillNumber in ('407','408','409','410','411','412','413','414', '439','440'))

and SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID from SRVY_InsightData_Excpt) --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  

AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pvt UNPIVOT 
(Response FOR 
Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
GROUP BY Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID


UNION ALL

/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/
/**************************************************  Employer and Individual ******************************************************************/

/* removed  '1180', '1209', '834', '809','718', ,'1074' '1392','1393',
added in  '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519'
*/

SELECT CASE
WHEN Site In ('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila', 'Int_Frederick', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu') THEN 'E&I'
ELSE Site END AS 'Line of Business'
, CAST((RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(MONTH(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(2)))) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(CALLDATE) AS CHAR(4))) AS DATETIME) AS Month
, Site
, skillnumber
, VCCNode
, calldate
, IVRCallerType
, SUM(1) AS Completed_Surveys
, Question
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes 
, SUM(CASE WHEN Response = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(/*    Unpivot the table.*/ 
SELECT Question, Response, Site, Bus_segment_type, calldate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            
(SELECT        Q7, site, Bus_segment_type, CallDate, SkillNumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID , SurveyID
FROM            SRVY_InsightData
WHERE        
--IVRCallerType IN (@ict) 
IVRCallerType in ('Provider', 'Clinical Intake')
AND (VCCNODE IN ('Eagan Node 7','Plymouth Node 1', 'Eagan Node 5') or VCCNode IS NULL)
AND Q7 IS NOT NULL 
AND Q7 <> '0' 
AND (((Site IN('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila',  'Int_Frederick', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu', 'PHS_Manila')
AND skillnumber IN ('718','735','736','1689','1690', '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519'))
 and CallDate < '2/1/2015') 

or ((Site IN('Belapur', 'Cebu', 'Frederick', 'Hookset', 'Huntsville', 'Kolkata', 'Manila', 'Moline', 'Moline PHS', 'Richardson',  'St. Louis','Tampa', 'Int_Richardson', 'Int_Manila', 'INT_Miramar', 'INT_Tampa', 'OGS_Cebu', 'WIPRO_Cebu', 'PHS_Manila')
AND skillnumber IN ('718','735','736','1689','1690', '718','730','780','781','1031','1032','1033','1034','1035','1036','1511','1512','1513','1514','1515','1516','1517','1521','1037','1519')) 
and CallDate >= '2/1/2015'))-- adding code to remove INT_Frederick after 2/1/2015 - FLH
AND SkillNumber not IN ('777', '215', '217','235','249') 
and SurveyID NOT IN  (SELECT SurveyID from SRVY_InsightData_Excpt) --where CallDate between Effective_DT and Expiry_Dt)  


AND calldate BETWEEN @start AND @end
) pvt UNPIVOT 
(Response FOR 
Question IN (Q7)) AS unpvt) AS Data
GROUP BY Question, Site, bus_segment_type, CallDate, skillnumber, VCCNode, IVRCallerType,ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID, SurveyID

) A left join D_PPSM_TINs B on A.ProviderTaxIDAgencyTaxID=B.TIN 
) final 
where
--[BIC_PILOT] in (@BIC_PILOT)
CHARINDEX(',' + [BIC_PILOT] + ',',','+ @BIC_PILOT + ',') > 0    
and
--Case when [Strategic_Account] is Null then 'Null' else [Strategic_Account]  end  in (@Strategic_Account)
( ([Strategic_Account] is Null AND CHARINDEX(','+ 'Null' + ',',','+ @Strategic_Account + ',')>0) OR ([Strategic_Account] is NOT Null AND CHARINDEX(','+ [Strategic_Account] + ',',','+ @Strategic_Account + ',')>0) )
and
--Case  when BIC is Null then 'No' else 'Yes' end in (@BIC)
( (BIC is Null AND CHARINDEX(','+ 'No' + ',',','+ @BIC + ',')>0) OR (BIC is NOT Null AND CHARINDEX(','+ 'Yes' + ',',','+ @BIC + ',')>0) )
and
--case when Expiry_dt = convert(varchar(10),'12/31/9999',121) then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end in (@Active) 
( (Expiry_dt=convert(varchar(10),'12/31/9999',121) AND CHARINDEX(','+ 'Active' + ',',','+ @Active + ',')>0) OR (Expiry_dt<>convert(varchar(10),'12/31/9999',121) AND CHARINDEX(','+ 'Inactive' + ',',','+ @Active + ',')>0) )
```

Comment: it still gives zero records

Comment: @Mohit Can you post the data you get when you execute without `where` clause?

Comment: I don't know how to paste the table data here

Comment: @Mohit, Atleast add some screenshot of the table data.

Comment: Just added an image of the data

Comment: @Mohit Can you show the values of `@BIC` and `@BIC_PILOT` which you passed while testing??

Comment: I just commented out the where conditions and executed the query

Answer (score 0):

Go through a process of systematically commenting out the content of your WHERE clause and re-running the query.

Run sub-queries individually to ensure they are behaving as expected.

Once you have a better understanding of where your query is failing then post more information.